# How to display [Object, objects] and execute *ngFor

Tags: angular

service:

```
public getLogs(){
 return this.http.get(`url.json`, {
  params: {
    supplier_id: id
  }
 })
}
```

html:

```
    <div *ngFor="let item of items | keyvalue">
        {{ item }}
    </div>
```

Component .ts:

```
public items: any;

ngOnInit() {

 this.service.getLogs().subscribe(items => this.items = items);
}
```

But I always get `[object Object]` What i need to change? (Also i tried to remove | keyvalue, but got error and [object Object])

Comment: An easy development step is to use the json pipe `{{ item | json }}` which will show how to access the object and what is accessible.

Comment: When i use it i got error. ``Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'TView'``

Comment: That’s a good hint that something very wrong with your expectation of what item is

Answer (score 1):

When referencing values returned from the `keyvalue` pipe, you can access the key and the value with `item.key` and `item.value`, respectively. [See keyvalue examples](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe#examples).

Additionally, per your comment, since `items` is an array, it does not have a key/value schema, only an array of values. To access the nested object data of the array elements, you'll need to add a nested `*ngFor`.

Lastly, your JSON returns an object with an `items` property - you should access that from the HTML.

```
// Iterate over the array elements here
<div *ngFor="let item of items.items">
  // Iterate over each element's key/value pairs
  <div *ngFor="let obj of item | keyvalue">
    {{ obj.key }} - {{ obj.value }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: With ``item.key`` i got ``_declarationTContainer``
``_declarationView``
``elementRef``, but not what i need. With ``item.value`` i got tons of text

Comment: @alex What data is being returned from the HTTP request? What does the JSON look like?

Comment: like: ``{"items":[{"timestamp":"2022-12-06,"message":"test"},{"timestamp":"2022-12-06",""message":"test"}]}``

Comment: I see - I updated my answer. You need a separate `*ngFor` to iterate over each element's key/value pairs.

Comment: For some reason still got error: ``Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.``

Comment: Take a look at this stackblitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vwcu6b?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

I'm able to access each key/value pair of each element in the array.

Comment: If past ``{"items":[{"timestamp":"2022-12-06", "message":"test"},{"timestamp":"2022-12-06","message":"test"}]}`` you will get same error :c

Comment: Updated the answer again.

Comment: I updated the stackblitz as well.

Comment: Yes, I see that it works correctly on stackblitz. But I have a blank page, although there is no error... :\ In the console, ``this.items`` has objects.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250196/discussion-between-paul-thorsen-and-alex).